# Warning while building project using Qt 5.1 on OSX

Tags: qt, warnings, qt-creator, qt5

I am getting two warnings while trying to build Qt projects on Mac (using QtCreator).

> warning: No .qmake.cache is present. This significantly slows down
>   qmake with this makespec. warning: Call 'cache()' in the top-level
>   project file to rectify this problem.

The warning instructs to call `cache()` in the top level project, but I don't find any documentation on how I should do that.

I see some bugs logged on qt

1. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31340
2. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-30586

I know this is just a warning, but I am interested in fixing it. Is there any workaround to fix it?

Comment: please select Kurt Pattyn's answer as correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to call cache() in your main .pro file.
Then run qmake (from the QtCreator build menu) and rebuild the project.
The warning should be gone.
Example .pro:

```
cache()

QT += ...
//the rest of the .pro file
```